# Yii. GridView filter is not working in IE8 and Opera (Firefox is fine)

Tags: internet-explorer, gridview, yii

Developing a site with Yii framework.

When I type keywords to search in the GridView filter input box and then hit `Enter` - the form is not submitted to the server. 
But hitting `Tab` or clicking with a mouse outside the input field - does work.

The problem is in IE and Opera. Firefox is fine.

**EDIT**

`dInGd0nG` suggested [this forum topic](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9732-critical-problem-in-ie-8-with-cgridview/) with a workaround for similar problem but `jquery.yiigridview.js` code has changed since the post of that workaround. It now uses `on()` function instead of `live()`.

The code is pretty different now, I'm not sure I'll be able to come up with new workaround myself.
Can anybody adapt that patch for current `jquery.yiigridview.js`?

So, as far as I understand, this is the piece that handles submition of filter input.

```
$(document).on('change', inputSelector, function () {
    var data = $(inputSelector).serialize();
    if (settings.pageVar !== undefined) {
        data += '&' + settings.pageVar + '=1';
    }
    $('#' + id).yiiGridView('update', {data: data});
});
```

It works in Firefox and doesn't work in IE or Opera.

Any ideas how to fix it?

**EDIT 2**

I came up with this to make IE and Opera send filter request on hitting `Enter` key.

```
if($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera) {
    $(document).on('keypress', inputSelector, function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            var data = $(inputSelector).serialize();
            if (settings.pageVar !== undefined) {
                data += '&' + settings.pageVar + '=1';
            }
            $('#' + id).yiiGridView('update', {data: data});
        }
    });
}
```

But it's kinda ugly.

Comment: This seems like a bug. Maybe report it on github.com/yiisoft/yii

Comment: Post your code, it could be that you have minor typo in your code. I have had code that worked in Chrome & FF but not in IE which was a typo on my part.

Comment: Just check a default gridview in IE8/9, it will not work, exactly as sevenWonders states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with jquery as stated [here](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1031). That page also has a work aorund. Have a look at this [forum post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9732-critical-problem-in-ie-8-with-cgridview/) too.